# File upload via FTP gaieerror Python 2.6

Tags: python

I'm trying to upload a text file to an FTP server, but I am getting this error:

`gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Here is my code.

```
        s = ftplib.FTP("ftp://xbrera.co.cc", "myuser", "mypass")
        f = open(path + "LD.txt", "r")
        s.storbinary("STOR " + path + "LD.txt")
        f.close()
        s.quit()
```

What am I doing wrong, and why am I getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to `s = ftplib.FTP("xbrera.co.cc", "myuser", "mypass")`. The `ftp://` is only mandatory for a URI but the ftplib library expect the hostname of your FTP server.